# What is cast iron guarantee in generics in java?

Tags: java, generics

Though i know that ,Generics is used to make our code more generalized and flexible .

But what does ***`cast iron guarantee`*** in `generics` and what it guarantees ?

**EDIT :** As this question is been asked from me in interview, so later I search on web too but only find one cast iron community but nothing related to such guarantee.

Comment: Is it just me, or is this a bit of BS to throw at an interviewee? "Cast iron guarantee" isn't in the JLS (put aside that it's probably stupid to expect an interviewee to quote JLS from memory), so this really boils down to "is your subjective/arbitrary definition of this term the same as mine?" I guess in this case it's "did you happen to read the same book I did, and memorize its terminology?" but that's hardly better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `cast-iron guarantee` says that, during the type erasure, the typecasts inserted by the compiler for generics are guaranteed to never fail, given that there were no unchecked warnings during compilation.

It basically means that the required type casts that the compiler inserts during the compilation of Generics will never cause a `ClassCastException` at run time, provided that there were no unchecked warnings during compilation.

More literally -

> Cast-iron guarantee: the implicit casts added by the compilation of
>   generics never fail.

taken from [Java Generics and Collections](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do).

Comment: "provided that there were no unchecked warnings during compilation." And provided that the classes you are using that were compiled by other people (including those from the Java standard library) did not have unchecked warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The other questions explain what this means.  I just want to point out that there are a couple of exceptions to the so-called "cast-iron" guarantee:

- If your codebase<sup>1</sup> contains statements that do unsafe conversions, etcetera (whether you see the messages, or whether you suppress them), then that *may* cause heap pollution.
- If your codebase uses reflection to perform operations on generic objects, then that *may* cause heap pollution.

In either case, this [heap pollution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155994/java-heap-pollution) can give rise to ClassCastExceptions.

---

Note that the phrase "cast-iron guarantee" does not appear in any Oracle documentation.  It seems to be the invention of a popular textbook ...

---

<sup>1 - The heap pollution could happen in library code that your sode is using.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The guarantee is that the compiler will ensure that all generic objects are of the specified concrete.

In practice, it means you will never get a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) when dealing with generics.

Without generics, *unsafe* explicit casts would be required. With generics, implicit *safe* casts are made.

Answer (score 1):

From the book "[Java Generics and Collections](http://books.google.com/books?id=zaoK0Z2STlkC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22cast%20iron%20guarantee%22%20java&source=bl&ots=6Xtqa7Y4HN&sig=-Wacp2ZItzZHEcJSlVYWd8Tipko&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hjIkUtDkFYqssQSS94CwCw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22cast%20iron%20guarantee%22%20java&f=false)":

> Cast-iron guarantee: the implicit casts added by the compilation of generics never fail

Answer (score 0):

A *cast iron guarantee* is something that you can completely trust / rely on.  What is curious about your question is that Java generics do **not** provide a *cast iron guarantee* of type safety.  Just a conditional one.

So, you need to indicate where did you find the expression to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `Generics` can be implemented on `variables`, `classes` , `methods` but it was specially designed to **type safe** the `collections`.

**-** When `Generics` were not introduced, the **object of any specific type would go inside the collection and would come out as Object type.**

**Eg:**

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
arr.(new Dog);

Dog d = (Dog) arr.get(0); // Explicit cast is required to get the specific type of object
```

**-** With the introduction of `Generics`, we became sure that when `a specific type goes into the collection it comes out as that same specific type.`

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
arr.(new Dog);

Dog d = arr.get(0); // No casting required.
```

**- Cast iron guarantee** means, that **all** the generic type will be of same specific type.

**-** Using generics will ensure that there will be **no type casting exception** during 
      `runtime`, as this casting issue is handled at compilation time itself.